# xargs sed and command substitution in bash

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep, xargs

I'm trying to pass a xargs string replace into a sed replacement inside of a substitution, here's the non-working code.

```
CALCINT=$CALCINT$(seq $CALCLINES | xargs -Iz echo $CALCINT' -F "invoiceid'z'="'$(sed -n '/invoiceid'z'/s/.*name="invoiceid'z'"\s\+value="\([^"]\+\).*/\1/p' output.txt))
```

Everything works up until the sed inside the second substitution. the 'z' should be a number 1-20 based on the $CALCLINES variable. I know it has something to do with not escaping properly for sed but I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how sed wants things escaped in this situation.

Here's the surrounding lines of code:

```
curl -b mycookiefile -c mycookiefile http://localhost/calcint.php > output.txt
CALCLINES=`grep -o 'class="addinterest"' output.txt | wc -l`
CALCINT=$CALCINT$(seq $CALCLINES | xargs -Iz echo $CALCINT' -F "invoiceid'z'="'$(sed -n '/invoiceid17/s/.*name="invoiceid17"\s\+value="\([^"]\+\).*/\1/p' output.txt))
echo $CALCINT
```

Output: (What I get now)

```
-F "invoiceid1=" -F "invoiceid2=" -F "invoiceid3=" -F "invoiceid4=" -F "invoiceid5=" -F "invoiceid6=" -F "invoiceid7=" -F "invoiceid8=" -F "invoiceid9=" -F "invoiceid10=" -F "invoiceid11=" -F "invoiceid12=" -F "invoiceid13=" -F "invoiceid14=" -F "invoiceid15=" -F "invoiceid16=" -F "invoiceid17=" -F "invoiceid18=" -F "invoiceid19=" -F "invoiceid20="
```

What I'm hoping to see as output is something like this

```
-F "invoiceid1=2342" -F "invoiceid2=456456" -F "invoiceid3=78987" ...etc etc
```

-------------------------EDIT-----------------------

FWIW...here's the output.txt and other things I've tried.

```
for i in $(seq -f "%02g" ${CALCLINES});do
sed -n "/interest$i/s/.*name=\"interest$i\"\s\+value=\"\([^\"]\+\).*/\1/p" output.txt > output2.txt
done
```

output2.txt contains nothing

Thanks to @janos response for clearing things up but taking a step back makes it clear to me that the root of the issue here is that I'm struggling to get the invoice ids out. It's dynamically generated HTML "....name="invoiceid7" value="556"..." so there isn't anything consistent in those particular tags that I can grep on, which is why I was counting another tag that IS consistent then trying to use a variable sed to basically deduce the tag name then extract the value.

Annd..output.txt https://pastebin.com/ewUaddVi

------UPDATE-----
Working solution

Stuff sed into a loop. Note how I had to use ' to use variables in the sed string. That is well documented elsewhere on here. :)

```
for i in $(seq ${CALCLINES});do
e="interest"$i`
CALCINT=$CALCINT' -F "'$e'='
CALCINT=$CALCINT$(sed -n '/'$e'/s/.*name="'$e'"\s\+value="\([^"]\+\).*/\1/p' output.txt)'"'
done
```

Please read through the comments on the solution below, there is a cleaner way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current approach cannot work, specifically this part:

```
... | xargs -Iz echo -F "invoiceid'z'="$(sed ...)"
```

The problem is that the `$(sed ...)` will not be evaluated for each line in the input during the execution of `xargs`.
The shell will evaluate this once, *before* it actually runs `xargs`.
And you need there dynamic values from your input.

You can make this work by taking a different approach:

1. Extract the invoice ids. For example, write a `grep` or `sed` pipeline that produces as output simply the list of invoice ids
2. Transform the invoice list to the `-F "invoiceidNUM=..."` form that you need

For the second step, Awk could be practical. The script could be something like this:

```
curl -b mycookiefile -c mycookiefile http://localhost/calcint.php > output.txt
args=$(sed ... output.txt | awk '{ print "-F \"invoice" NR "=" $0 "\"" }')
echo $args
```

For example if the `sed` step produces 2342, 456456, 78987, then the output will be:

```
-F "invoice1=2342" -F "invoice2=456456" -F "invoice3=78987"
```

Comment: Got it that makes sense but I guess the root of the issue here is that I'm struggling to get the invoice ids out. It's dynamically generated HTML "....name="invoiceid7" value="556"..." so there isn't anything consistent in those particular tags that I can grep on, which is why I was counting another tag that IS consistent then trying to use a variable sed to basically deduce the tag name then extract the value.

Comment: @Blinder Can't you just do `grep -o invoiceid'[0-9]*'` ?

Comment: yes but that only gets my halfway there. Plus I don't know how many elements there will be each time. It would be nice if they would do the work in the DB so I could use curl to pass a list of invoice IDs to charge interest but it's all done client side so I'm having to chop away at the HTML. In the end I was able to make sed happy enough inside a loop like this:
for i in $(seq ${CALCLINES});do
    e="interest"$i
    CALCINT=$CALCINT' -F "'$e'='
    CALCINT=$CALCINT$(sed -n '/'$e'/s/.*name="'$e'"\s\+value="\([^"]\+\).*/\1/p' output.txt)'"'
done

Comment: @Blinder If you share a sample input and the desired list of ids to extract from it, I suspect it can be done with a simpler `sed` and without looping. But that deserves it's own separate question.

Comment: If you're (or anyone else is) feeling adventurous the pastebin link above is the sample input. The goal is to get the value attributes for all input tag names interestX invoiceidX and curX. X starts at 1 and goes to infinity based on whatever the software outputs.  Still working on this project but this question is solved

Comment: @Blinder you could extract from that the values with `grep -Eo 'name="invoiceid[0-9]+" value="[0-9]+' output.txt | sed -e 's/.*"//'`